# Add edges with plane blender

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

Im trying to figure out a way to quickly make x and y loop cuts. I want to use planes to add edges where the planes surface touches the object's surfaces.
[image: this is the set up Im looking for]

I know I could use the knife tool but Im trying to use this for a lot of objects so I suspect I could instance a bunch of planes at the center of these objects pretty easily if the planes would do the cutting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the cutting planes are in the configuration shown in your picture, you can use "knife project" to cut several objects at once.

[image]

Select all the objects you want to cut and enter edit mode.

Select the cutting object.

Place the view above them all in top orthographic.

And use "knife project" (make sure the "cutting through" option is activated in the operator panel).